# Обрезать с добавлением многоточия многострочный форматированный текст по размеру скрытого контейнера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Собственно есть:

- jQuery
- Плагин [jQuery dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) для обрезки форматированного текста по размеру контейнера.
- Плагин [jQuery Actual](https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual) для измерения размера скрытых элементов.

По отдельности всё работает. Проблема возникает, когда надо обрезать текст в скрытом контейнере. В лучшем случае обрезка просто не работает, в худшем - падает с исключением о невозможности присвоить содержимое тега br.

Как при помощи этих или каких-либо других плагинов сделать обрезку текста по размеру скрытого контейнера?

Делал разные эксперименты от передачи высоты как параметра, до попытки подмены методов jQuery на методы плагина, но ничем хорошим они не кончились.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhs513ws/1/

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $($(this).data("dest")).find("div").dotdotdot().end().show();
  });
});
```

```css
section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 256px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4hAcxkH4"></script> <!-- dotdotdot -->
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KpmR9HmG"></script> <!-- actual -->

<p>
  <button data-dest="#visible">На видимой</button>
  <button data-dest="#hidden">На скрытой</button>
</p>

<section id="visible">
  <div><strong>CyberLink PowerDirector 12</strong> выводит процесс создания видео на абсолютно новый уровень. Функция <em>MultiCam</em> поддерживает до 4 камер, что позволяет пользователю работать с записями, произведенными несколькими устройствами одновременно. Программа включает в себя модуль Theme Designer, который позволяет создавать безупречные анимационные 3D слайд-шоу из видео и фотографий.</div>
</section>

<section id="hidden">
  <div><strong>CyberLink PowerDirector 12</strong> выводит процесс создания видео на абсолютно новый уровень. Функция <em>MultiCam</em> поддерживает до 4 камер, что позволяет пользователю работать с записями, произведенными несколькими устройствами одновременно. Программа включает в себя модуль Theme Designer, который позволяет создавать безупречные анимационные 3D слайд-шоу из видео и фотографий.</div>
</section>
```

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32215283/4928642).

Comment: Можно при загрузке страницы пройтись по всем элементам и сразу обрезать текст

Comment: @lolbas, не понял, чем мне это должно помочь. Если элемент скрытый, то он и при загрузке страницы скрытый, а значит, плагин не сработает.

Comment: Долой плагин тогда. Можно написать маленькую функцию, которая определяла нужнфе параметры скрытых объектов. Сейчас к сурсу нет доступа, вкратце - сохранение старых стилей, присваивание `display: block`, измерение параметров, возврат исходных стилей

Comment: @lolbas, установка `display:block` сделает элемент видимым для пользователя, поэтому не походит.

Comment: Откуда такая уверенность? Мы же делаем его видимым на очень короткое время http://jsfiddle.net/buqLvjyw/

Comment: @lolbas, то, что браузер не успевает показать элемент, не означает, что он никогда не будет показан. Особенно, что какой-нибудь IE8 его не покажет. А ещё, я уже немного изменил вопрос (сначала эту деталь упустил) - dotdotdot применяется не к скрытому элементу, а к одному из его потомков. Получается, что надо всех родителей показать, а потом вернуть как было - не слишком хорошо.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32215283/4928642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, придумал нечто работающее. Завтра попытаюсь приделать использовать этот код. Спасибо всем, предложившим временно показать элемент, а также сдвинуть его за пределы экрана. Хотя эти варианты сами по себе не являются решением, они направили мои мысли в нужном направлении.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhs513ws/7/

```js
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var $container = $($(this).data("dest")), $dest = $container.find(".dest");
        
        if ($dest.is(":visible")) {
            $dest.dotdotdot();
        } else {
            var $marker = $("<div>");
            
            var width = $dest.actual('width'), height = $dest.actual('height');
            
            var $temp = $("<div>").css({
                position: 'fixed',
                left: '-99999px'
            }).appendTo("body");
            
            $marker.replaceWith(
             $dest
                 .before($marker)
                 .width(width).height(height)
                 .detach().appendTo($temp).dotdotdot()
                 .detach()
                 .width("").height("")
            );
            
            $temp.remove();
        }
        
        $container.show();
    });
});
```

```css
section {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 256px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

.dest {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}

#hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4hAcxkH4"></script> <!-- dotdotdot -->
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KpmR9HmG"></script> <!-- actual -->

<p>
    <button data-dest="#visible">На видимой</button>
    <button data-dest="#hidden">На скрытой</button>
</p>

<section id="visible">
    <div>123</div>
    <div class="dest"><strong>CyberLink PowerDirector 12</strong> выводит процесс создания видео на абсолютно новый уровень. Функция <em>MultiCam</em> поддерживает до 4 камер, что позволяет пользователю работать с записями, произведенными несколькими устройствами одновременно. Программа включает в себя модуль Theme Designer, который позволяет создавать безупречные анимационные 3D слайд-шоу из видео и фотографий.</div>
    <div>456</div>
</section>

<section id="hidden">
    <div>123</div>
    <div class="dest"><strong>CyberLink PowerDirector 12</strong> выводит процесс создания видео на абсолютно новый уровень. Функция <em>MultiCam</em> поддерживает до 4 камер, что позволяет пользователю работать с записями, произведенными несколькими устройствами одновременно. Программа включает в себя модуль Theme Designer, который позволяет создавать безупречные анимационные 3D слайд-шоу из видео и фотографий.</div>
    <div>456</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Там оказалось сложнее, но общая идея вроде съедобная.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно такой метод вам подойдет:

```
#hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999999px;
    top: - 9999999px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4d65hLn7/

Comment: Видимостью и размещением блоков управляет другой плагин. И, повторюсь, скрыт не сам блок, а один из его родителей. Получается, что надо запомнить видимость родителей, потом их показать (эм.. а какому из них положение испортить?), применить плагин, а потом восстановить.

Comment: Не очень понял как способ скрытия элемента со страницы влияет на функционал в целом, но видимо это связано с тем, что я не в курсе всех подробностей проекта.